# Javascript replace dynamic text in string

Tags: javascript, replace

If i have a string as follows:

```
http:/mydomain.com/index.php/this/is/an/amazing/url/param/560/
```

and i want to replace the value of 560, what is the way to do this.

Would a regex or string function be best used here and if so what would that be since the value can be different.

i.e.

the value can be anything:

```
http:/mydomain.com/index.php/this/is/an/amazing/url/param/120/
http:/mydomain.com/index.php/this/is/an/amazing/url/param/200/
```

also the trailing slash may be missing i.e.

```
http:/mydomain.com/index.php/this/is/an/amazing/url/param/560
```

Comment: Yes, use .replace() with regex

Comment: When you say "the value can be anything", do you mean you want to replace any number at the end of the URL, or the value is a dynamic input to the program?

Comment: And if the original URL ends with `/`, does that have to be retained in the result?

Comment: Hi, yes to both of those

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
var new_number = 5;

url = url.replace(/\d+(\/)?$/, new_number + "$1");
```

This looks for numbers, then optionally one slash, then the end of the string. So you won't match things like `http://example.com/some/other/1234/numbers`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. This is a good answer even though (\/) looks like a vulgar ascii art.

Comment: Ha, I suppose it does! I think that just adds to its charm.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is probably the easiest solution in this case:

```
url.replace(/\/\d+\/?$/, '/' + newNumber);
```

This Regex specifically looks for anything ending in a slash, 1 or more digits, then an optional slash.

Comment: this will result in `param123`; don't forget to replace the `/` before the number.

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = new RegExp('\b'+value+'\b');
newurl = url.replace($regExp, newvalue);
```